# Any recommendations how to deploy dependencies for NUnit tests like Visual Studio 2010 testing does?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nunit, resharper

How do I set up VS 2010 and NUnit to deploy dependencies for tests like the built in Visual Studio Testing Tools?

The built in tools allow you mark files or folders to deploy with your tests (through "Test Settings: Deployment"). It groups test output into directories sorted by date.

I would like to get something like that working with NUnit (which is awesome, esp with Resharper);

The closest I have been able to come with NUnit is adding this command as a post build event for my test project, where all the files my tests need are in TestResources directory:

```
xcopy.exe $(ProjectDir)\TestResources . /E /Y
```

I couldn't find anything on the interwebs, Resharper, or NUnit documentation... and I got lost in the MSBuild docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can files or folders to be copied in the Property Inspector, and they'll be copied over o the output folder. Set the Build Action to "Content": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0c6xyb66(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks Adam, that seems only to work for individual files though, right?  The files that my tests require are numerous and in various nested folders in my TestResources directory.

Comment: For a large number of folders, the xcopy approach in a post-build action is probably the best bet.